# CSS VW and VH - maintain ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that contains a DIV which maintains an aspect ratio. I have some text within the div that uses VW on the font size which maintains the text size when the page width changes - which is great.

But when the user changes the window height - I cannot get it to respond in the same way - because VW and VH don't play together.

Is there some CSS or Javascript trickery to get this to work? Ideally on the fly in case the user changes the browser size whilst on the site?

Here is said problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lp8jynfr/1/

```
<style>
.page-wrapper{
    width: 100vw; 
    height: 68.60vw; /* height:width ratio = 9/16 = .5625  */
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 145.7vh; /* 16/9 = 1.778 */
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0; /* vertical center */
    left:0;right:0; /* horizontal center */
    border: 5px solid #000;
}

.text{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:36%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    font-size: 5.6vw;
    color:#2d90db;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>

<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="text">
  This is some text I want resized
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "VW and VH don't play together"? The aspect ratio is always the same!?

Comment: You can try to use CSS calc to calculate the correct sizes. e.g. `width: calc(100vw / 1.6)` or `width: calc(100vw / 3vh)`.

Comment: you've got to do this in two separate cases: one where height is the limiting factor and another where width is the limiting factor.  update the class based on that, using the resize handler (https://api.jquery.com/resize/ since you're using jQuery).  The font-size will be proportional to vw in one case and vh in the other.

Comment: Take a look at vmin or vmax if you want a property that will depend on the smallest or largest side of the viewport respectively.

Comment: Here is an update of your fiddle, using the `vmin` _Davey_ suggested: https://jsfiddle.net/Lp8jynfr/2/

Comment: @Davey Post an answer, use my fiddle if you like .. and I give you an upvote

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle! This nearly works! - but as you start to scale down the page width, the text stays the same size until youre around 60% of the original div size, and only then does it start scaling down the text. Am I missing something? :/

Comment: @user3706091 No, you didn't miss anything, that happens because the width and height is not equal. Next step is a script to calc the font size

Comment: Hey, I think the fiddle that @LSGon provides is a good example of how to use vmin. I did have a look around for a different solution, but, do you think LSGon's answer might actually be what you want? So with this solution the text will _always_ be dependant on the size of the bounding box. The behaviour you describe is when you are changing window size without affecting the box size.

Comment: I made a slight mistake, LSGon's jsfiddle would have been great if your bounding box was a square. Please take a look at the answer that I've submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing some Jquery to get this to work, it works pretty smoothly

I added an attribute to the DIV to tell the Jquery a font size, then did some calculations on the height of the parent container to get it to scale depending on the height of the DIV

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {

    $('.resize').height(function(){
        $height = $(this).parent().parent().height();
        $datasize = $(this).attr("data-size");
        $fontsize = $height/100  * $datasize+"px"
        $(this).css("font-size",$fontsize);
    });

}).resize();

<div class='resize' data-size="9">Some text I want to resize</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/davey182673/Lp8jynfr/4/ It uses the following media query to detect the viewport aspect ratio.

```
...
.text {
    font-size: 5.625vw;
}

/* at the point when the media query is applied */
/* 5.625vw = 10vh */
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .text {
    font-size: 10vh ;
  }
}
```